# React Javascript Array intrinsics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I want to contain the Title array using the map function, but I get an error. How to modify the code?

How do I fix the code to avoid the error? I m only doing this for today. I think I m really stupid

First, get data from CartData.

```
const { data: CartData, error: CartError } = useSWR(http://localhost:3060/user/Carts, fetcher)
```

I tried console.log.

console.log(CartData);

```
Object
email: alstntorl@naver.com
id: 1
Cartd: Array(4)
0: {id: 1, 
Title: 나이키 x 앰부쉬 덩크  딥 로얄 블루, 
 …}
1: {id: 11, 
Title: 뉴발란스 2002R 그레이, 
 …}
2: {id: 34, Title: 컨버스 하이크 하이 블랙 화이트 검,, …}
3: {id: 36, Title: 아디다스 이지 부스트 380 미스트, 10, …}
length: 4
```

I am trying to get Title information using the map function. But I get an error here.

```
 const result = CartData.Cartd.map((list) => list.Title);
 console.log(result);
```

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read property Cartd of undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
.next\server\pages\mypage.js (32:28) @ mypage

  30 | 
  31 | 
> 32 |     const result = CartData.Cartd.map((list) => list.Title);
     |                            ^
  33 |     console.log(result);
  34 | 
  35 |
```

Comment: React is rendering the component for the first time before the data is loaded. You cannot use `CartData.Cartd.map` while `CartData.Cartd` is `undefined`.

Comment: I really don't know, So how do you modify the code?

Comment: Something like `const result = CartData.Cartd ? CartData.Cartd.map((list) => list.Title) || [];` for instance, or you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: ` const result = CartData.Cartd ? CartData.Cartd.map((list) => list.Title) || [];`
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ":" is displayed.   Teachers are welcome to modify the code. I just need to print the title. Please help

Comment: Yeah sorry, `||` is supposed to be `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its because of react-life-cycle or asynchronous. Whatever it is, You have to consider it both. so I think that maybe the value should be not 'const'.

And I suggest optional chaining in your code. like

```
let result = CardData?.Carted?.map(blahblah)
```

Comment: `
 let result = CartData?.Carted?.map((list) => list.Title)
 console.log(result); ` .
After listening to the teacher, I tried to console the result, but an undefined value came out. Is the undefined value coming out?

Comment: In optional chaining, if prev_value is null or undefined, whole value return undefined. so that's right way.  In other words, It means your 'CardData' or 'Carted' is null. In this way, if you get data from network, It can not be synchronous .

Comment: I suggest you search about async-await and react-life-cycle.